# Css animate infinite animated line

Tags: html, css, animation, keyframe

Not sure if this can be done with css, otherwise I will look for a way to do it with js.
I want to create an infinite and smooth animation which constantly repeats itself.

This dotted arrow line should be constantly flowing without ending.

```
[ICON] --->--->----> [ICON]
```

I'm not getting very far with css here.

```css
.arrows {
  position: absolute;
  animation: arrows 2s infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes arrows {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 5px;
  }
  80% {
    left: 15px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="arrows">-->-->--></div>
```

The problem for me is not to make the animation smoother, but to let the arrows repeat them self without jumping pack to the starting point of `0px`

thanks

Comment: Something like `<marquee>->->-></marquee>` ?

Comment: hm @Baldráni this looks promising

Comment: `<marquee>` has been deprecated and is obsolete  and should no longer be used. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: @xhallix check my answer.

Comment: @Paulie_D Ho I didn't knew so I guess the only option left is javascript then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.arrows {
  position: absolute;
  animation: arrows 1s infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   -webkit-animation: arrows 1s;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
}
@keyframes arrows {
  0% {
    left: 10%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="arrows">-->-->--></div>
```

Comment: @Baldráni now check it.

Comment: sorry that is not what I'm looking for, because you can see it's jumping back to the start which makes it not look infinite

Comment: @xhallix now check

Comment: @xhallix Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite good, but might be useful for you:

```css
.arrows-container
{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 8ex;
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 1em;
}
.arrows {
  position: absolute;
  animation: arrows 2s infinite linear;
  width: 20ex;
  left: -7ex;
}
@keyframes arrows {
  0%{left: -7ex;}
  50%{left: -4ex;}
  100%{left: -1ex;}
}
```

```html
<div class="arrows-container">
  <div class="arrows">-->-->-->-->-->--></div>
</div>
```

**Also, you need not specify `animation-iteration-count` again when you have already specified it in the shorthand rule `animation`.**

Answer (score 0):

Is the balise `<marquee>` sufficient or do you look for a whole loop effect without break ? If it's the case I don't think you can do it without javascript.

If marquee is sufficient here is an exemple.

```html
<marquee BEHAVIOR="slide" DIRECTION="right" LOOP="2">->->-></marquee>
```